# Cannot connect to MacOS Mojave via VNC from Windows 10

Tags: mac, remote-desktop, vnc, debug, macos-mojave

I am trying to connect to my MacOS Mojave via VNC. I have enabled "Remote Management" in "System Preferences" > "Sharing" and added me and/or all other users to the users that are allowed to have access. Furthermore, in a second attempt I have enabled "VNC users may control screen with password" in "Computer Settings". The firewall is disabled.

Nothing I have tried so far worked. When I try to connect to the Mac, both via IP and name, TightVNC and VNC-Viwer (Windows 10) and Remmina (Ubuntu, WSL on Windows 10) all fail to connect, without any *proper* error message, something along the lines of "Cannot connect" or "Host did not respond properly".

I had another Mac with an older OS (cannot remember which one). I typed "open vnc://hostname" and it worked on first attempt. However, I want to be able to log into my Mac using my Windows 10 Laptop. I can connect to the local network via VPN. I can `ssh` into the mac without problems (and even get an X11 connection).

What are other steps I can take to debug this problem? Did I miss any steps in trying to set up this connection?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have tried using many different Windows clients, but did you ever think that the problem might be the server?
Apple has a tendency to make their own [everything], which can be either good or bad. I am not an Apple user, but my wild guess is that they made their own protocols for remote management (similar but different from VNC).

> My experience with Mac OS X provided VNC, is that generally it works very well when talking Mac OS X VNC server to Mac OS X VNC Client.
>
> But when either Mac OS X client or server talks with a 3rd party VNC
> server or client, things are not always happy.
>
> ...
>
> Remote Management is really intended for the "Apple Remote Desktop" (ARD) package.  ARD is intented to manage a room full of Macs, such as a classroom environment.  It is not intended for VNC clients.

~ [BobHarris](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3122688?answerId=15425817022#15425817022)

For such a task, I will suggest that you use a reputable, cross-platfrom VPN **Server**. I would recommend [RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com/en/). You can get the server [here](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/) and the client ("viewer") [here](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/). For personal use, it is free. These links are non-affiliate links.

If you'd really like to continue using the built-in feature, try [BobHarris](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3122688?answerId=15425817022#15425817022)'s advice.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed TightVNC on Windows 10. Accessing it from Catalina via `open vnc://<remote ip>` works. You have to configure a password on the Windows side. Won't work without.